# How to pass multiple domain and local user accounts into a function

Tags: function, powershell, variables, account

I have a script that I have been trying to massage and I want to take a loop that was copied multiple times for each user and I want to turn it into a function.
I have figured out to pass multiple local users to the script and I have been able to pass one domain user to the script and have it work successfully.

But I want to be able to create a list of users and their domains (some have none)
and pipe that into the function automatically. I know I could just keep writing out the function with each username and password but If I can avoid that, that would be great

```
Function Launch-cfm {
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
[string] $username,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
[string] $domain
)
if ($domain -eq $tue) {
Stop-Process -name "autohotkey" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
&$OutFile

$user = "$username"
$user_sam = ($members | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains $user
if ($user_sam -eq $true) {

$user = "$username"
$account = $user
$PassFile = $CredPath+$user+,"_Password.txt"
$keyFile = $CredPath+$user+,".key"
$key = Get-content $keyFile
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $account, (Get-Content $PassFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

Write-Host "info to user about scripts actions."
C:
Start-Process -FilePath $mmcPath -ArgumentList $mscPath -Credential $cred;pause 
} else { Write-Host "$user does not exist on this server!!!! Moving on...!
"}

} else {
Stop-Process -name "autohotkey" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
&$OutFile

$user = "$username"
$user_sam2 = ($members | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -contains $user
if ($user_sam2 -eq $true) {
$account = $domain+,"\"+$user
$PassFile = $CredPath+$user+,"_Password.txt"
$keyFile = $CredPath+$user+,".key"
$key = Get-content $keyFile
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $account, (Get-Content $PassFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
Write-Host "info to user about scripts actions"

Start-Process -FilePath $mmcPath -ArgumentList $mscPath -Credential $cred;pause
} else { Write-Host "$user does not exist on this server!!!! Moving on...!
"}


}
}


$use = "User1","user2"
$dom = "domain1",""
launch-cfm -username $use -domain $dom
```

any suggestion would be great. or to know if what I am asking is even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: `if ($domain -eq $tue) {` <-- did you mean this to be `-eq $true` ?

Comment: no it should be -ne $null

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are looking for is a never ending parameter. Give this a try.

Input: `Launch-cfm -usernames "Drew","Cleadus","Stack" -domain "SuperDomain1337"`

```
Function Launch-cfm {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string[]] $usernames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string] $domain
    )

    Foreach($user in $usernames){
        Do-Magic
    }
}
```

**Reasoning:**

I am not a fan of positional parameters, throw them where they feel right in the moment.

Using `[string[]]` instead of `[string]` means that it will put all values passed to it into an array for later use within the function. This current configuration allows for MULTIPLE users but only ONE domain. You can change that but would need to iterate over each domain and user at a time, unless specified within the script some how.

EG.

```
Foreach($dom -in $domain){
    Foreach($user in $usernames){
        Do-Magic
    } Else {
        Do-LessImpressiveMagic
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. The above will above will only allow me to run against one user.
when entering in multiple usernames for the same domain the script will not run.